# How to center, to align left, to align right and to justify the algorithm title using the algorithm2e latex package?

Tags: algorithm2e

I am migrating to algorithm2e package. I would like to align the algorithm title as justified according to the text column width. But I also would like to know how to align left, to align right and to center the title.

My MWE attempt:

```
\documentclass[brazil,twocolumn]{article}



\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[portuguese,portuguesekw,linesnumbered,vlined,ruled,commentsnumbered,algo2e]{algorithm2e}



\begin{document}

\twocolumn[]

\lipsum[1-3]

The algorithm with \verb|algorithm2e| package:

\begin{algorithm2e}[h]

    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwFunction{ProcedureTitle}{Teste}
    \SetKwProg{KwPcdr}{Procedure}{}{end}
    \DontPrintSemicolon

    \BlankLine

    \KwIn{$a$, $b$, $c$.}
    \KwOut{$d$, $e$, $f$.}

    \BlankLine

    \KwPcdr{\ProcedureTitle{$a$, $b$, $c$}}{
        \BlankLine  
        \While{not at end of this document}{
            read current\;
            \eIf{understand}{
                go to next section\;
                current section becomes this one\;
            }{
                go back to the beginning of current section\;
            }
        }       
        \KwRet{$d$, $e$, $f$}   }

    \caption{A long caption is being placed here. I would like to typeset breaklines and full caption box size (i.e., height and width for the ``Algorithm #1: title string'' set).}
    \label{alg:attempt}

\end{algorithm2e}



\end{document}
```

The execution results of aforementioned code:

[image: Fig. 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redefined `\algocf@makecaption@ruled` to use the whole column, minus `\AlgoCapHskip` on both sides.  This will have no effect on boxed or other format captions.

I also added `\thealgorithm` to enable one to access the caption number, and `\SetAlgoCaptionFormat` to facilitate other formatting styles (like `\centering`, `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`).

```
\documentclass[brazil,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[portuguese,portuguesekw,linesnumbered,vlined,ruled,commentsnumbered,algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}% set caption margins

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic\algocf@float}

\newcommand{\AlgoCaptionFormat}{}
\newcommand{\SetAlgoCaptionFormat}[1]{\def\AlgoCaptionFormat{#1}}

\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption@ruled}[2]{%
  \global\sbox\algocf@capbox{\hskip\AlCapHSkip%
    \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}% restored on exit of sbox
    \addtolength{\hsize}{-2\AlCapHSkip}% add equal margin to both sides
    \vtop{\AlgoCaptionFormat\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}}% then caption is not centered
}%
\makeatother

%\SetAlgoCaptionFormat{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[]

\lipsum[1-3]

The algorithm with \verb|algorithm2e| package:

\begin{algorithm2e}[h]

    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwFunction{ProcedureTitle}{Teste}
    \SetKwProg{KwPcdr}{Procedure}{}{end}
    \DontPrintSemicolon

    \BlankLine

    \KwIn{$a$, $b$, $c$.}
    \KwOut{$d$, $e$, $f$.}

    \BlankLine

    \KwPcdr{\ProcedureTitle{$a$, $b$, $c$}}{
        \BlankLine  
        \While{not at end of this document}{
            read current\;
            \eIf{understand}{
                go to next section\;
                current section becomes this one\;
            }{
                go back to the beginning of current section\;
            }
        }       
        \KwRet{$d$, $e$, $f$}   }

    \caption{A long caption is being placed here. I would like to typeset breaklines and full caption box size (i.e., height and width for the ``Algorithm \thealgorithm: title string'' set).}
    \label{alg:attempt}
\end{algorithm2e}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: That is great solution! It is exactly what I was looking for. I tested your solution and it worked fine in my context. Thank you by help.